# How to copy values out of a Realm Object to pass to another thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, realm

I have a Realm Object (let's call it File) with a String property called `url`.
I have created an Alamofire `DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination` block which contains a reference to the `url` so I can download the file.  However, because this block gets executed on a background thread, Realm throws up an exception.  I don't need to actually access the entire Realm, or even the entire File object - only the property `url` - so there is no reason to try to open the File object from the Realm in the background thread.

What is the proper way to copy this string (or properties of other types) out of the Realm object to pass to a different thread?

My current solution seems very inelegant - though it does work.

`let url = "\(object.url)"`

This question is not related to a specific block of code - it is more a conceptual question.

Comment: Please be more specific about your types. Is the type of `url` Swift’s `String`? If so, that’s a value type, so what does you mean by having a “reference” to it?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, if you read the [Realm's docs for threading](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading), it said `you cannot have multiple threads sharing the same instances of Realm objects`, that mean you fetch the `File` object on the main thread, you cannot use it on other thread, in your case is Alamofire background thread

What you did is correct, assigning the value of url to another variable, else, just call `fetchFile().url` where `fetchFiles()` return the file object from Realm (refetch the file object -  but this will have worse performance, only useful in other case where the realm object changed a lot)

Comment: I understand this is the expected behavior for Realm.  My question was how to work within these constraints.  Will simply assigning the property, such as `let url = object.url` unlink it from Realm and it's live updating objects?

Comment: Yes, as i said, its the correct way if you simply wish to use it, or just refetch it on other thread by passing fetching function to alamofire instead of passing realm object if you need to change it from multiple thread

Answer (score 0):

Simply assigning `let url = object.url` will copy the value and is thread safe.